# Cannot load message class for [kobuki_msgs/BumperEvent]. Are your messages built?

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have a turtlebot2 hooked onto a laptop and configured a remote pc/workstation to access it as well. catkin packets created on the remote pc are running smoothly on the turtlebot, but when I try to get the data from some /mobile_base/... topics such as /mobile_base/events/bumper It says,

> BumperEvent from kobuki_msgs.msg
> module not found

When I try to echo the rostopic from the kobuki notebook, I dont get anything. the console just stays there locked forever till I terminate it.
When I try to do the same from the remote pc, I get the

> cannot load message class for [kobuki_msgs/BumperEvent].

actually from the /mobile_base ... only the  /mobile_base/debug/... work. the reset give the cannot load message error from the remote pc. However, other, topics such as cmd_mux_vel ... work without issues.
What could be the cause of this?
How can I resolve it?
Thanks alot in advance.

PS. according to the kobuki_dashboard -> /mobile_base_nodelet_manager, all the topics are published. and rosmsg show works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306126/cannot-load-message-class-for-%5Bkobuki_msgs/bumperevent%5D.-are-your-messages-built?/) by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2018-10-18**:
oh alright. Let me trythat out soon - install them on the remote pc as well. I hadnt installed all of them on the remote pc. just a few of them.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2018-10-23**:
@gvdhoorn, can you convert this to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed all the relevant TB2 packages on your laptop and remote pc/workstation?

You must have the message pkgs installed on all hosts that wish to participate in the communication, or things won't work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1